# During MongoDB Failover DB Operations Take Minutes to Finish

Tags: mongodb, failover, replicaset

I hope you could give me pointers for what to look for to understand and further debug the following behavior:

I have a MongoDB replica set (3 nodes) which was moved to different machines and hence had two failovers. All went well without any errors or data loss, except that the DB operations made by my application server took up to 7 minutes and not milliseconds to finish.

What happened is quite simple: As soon as the topology changed – e.g. the primary shut down and the secondary was elected as primary – the DB operations made by my node.js application server started to take long. This piled up dozens of db operations which all finished minutes later all at once / in quick succession.

My suspicion is – I could be wrong – that a write operation with `writeConcern: 'majority'` was made right after the topology change and then was only able to finish once the replica set was fully available again 7 minutes later, i.e. the shut down primary was back up as a new secondary. And I heard that the `mongodb` node.js driver only processes DB operations sequentially and thus even the read operations that came after the aforementioned write operation had to wait in a queue. So once the write operation finished, all other read operations could quickly finish as well.

So far my theory. However, labelling the a write operation with `writeConcern: 'majority'` as the culprit doesn’t make fully sense because at the point at which my replica set has only 2 nodes during those 7 minutes, the write operation should be able to finish with writing to these two nodes as far as I understand it.

Do you think there is truth to my theory? Or is there something else, e.g. some driver settings, that I am just not aware of?

Thanks a lot for your help!

**UPDATE**: After further investigation it seems that `writeConcern: 'majority'` and even `readConcern: 'majority'` are indeed the culprit because I use a so-called “PSA Replica Set” which has [these documented performance implications](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/mitigate-psa-performance-issues/) that sound exactly like what I experienced.

I changed my code to use `writeConcern: 1` and `readConcern: 1` and did not have issues since then. However, I did not verify if another failover occurred since then.

Comment: just in case check your rollback folder...

Comment: @R2D2 Good point! Thanks for making me aware of this. :)

Comment: Just curiosity: Was there something inside? :)

Answer (score 1):

Given the provided information one can only speculate.

> All went well without any errors or data loss, except that the DB operations made by my application server took up to 7 minutes and not milliseconds to finish.

> the DB operations made by my node.js application server started to take long.

At this point you needed to identify where the time was being spent:

- waiting for there to be a suitable server in topology for your operation
- waiting to get a connection to that server
- waiting for the server to respond

Given the information you did provide, your speculation is at least as good as that of anyone on this site.

Node driver specifically is not compliant with driver specifications in its default configuration (meaning it doesn't behave in ways that many people commonly expect it to behave), so that's another factor that could be causing a whole separate set of issues.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your pointers buddy! I was out of ideas how to further get to the bottom of this and your thoughts give me great direction. I will set up a testing environment where I can hopefully reproduce the issue and then have a closer look at the things that you said. Later I will update this post to add my findings so that others can learn from it. Thanks again!